# If and Else statements on Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, if-statement

I am having problems figuring out in which order these if and else statements need to be arranged in Visual Basic 2010 Express. As you can probably tell from the code, when it is working properly the program should display data found in a text file externally. If this data is not found then an error message in a label should appear.
Thanks for the help.

Code:

```
   Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim filename As String = "..\..\usernamepassword.txt"
    Dim objreader As New System.IO.StreamReader(filename)
    Dim contents As String
    Dim check As String
    Dim checkfile As New System.IO.StreamReader("..\..\checkfile.txt")
    check = checkfile.ReadToEnd
    For i As Integer = 1 To check
        contents = objreader.ReadLine
        Dim data As New List(Of String)(contents.Split(","))
        If forename.Text = data(2) Then
     'first if statement is here \/
            If surname.Text = data(3) Then
                fullname.Text = (data(2) & " " & data(3))
                dob.Text = data(4)
                phone.Text = data(5)
                address.Text = data(6)
                password.Text = data(1)
           'else statement \/
            Else
                Label2.Text = "Sorry, no result found for this student."
                Label5.Text = "Please note this system is caps sensitive."
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    Dim s As String = ""
    forename.Text = s
    surname.Text = s
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: What does your full line contains?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean, sorry

Comment: In the text File, What does a line contains of Like first name then middle name then password

Comment: Here is the content of the text file:

Comment: its basically about 7/8 lines of that but just with different names and passwords

Comment: What does checkfile.txt contains?

Comment: checkfile.txt literally just contains one number, its so that whenever you click button 2 it adds 1 to that file

Comment: Storing user names and plaintext passwords in a text file never ends well

Answer (score 0):

You should handle it like this

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
Dim filename As String = "..\..\usernamepassword.txt"
Dim found as Boolean = False
Dim objreader As New System.IO.StreamReader(filename)
Dim contents As String
Dim check As String
Dim checkfile As New System.IO.StreamReader("..\..\checkfile.txt")
check = checkfile.ReadToEnd
For i As Integer = 1 To check
    contents = objreader.ReadLine
    Dim data As New List(Of String)(contents.Split(","))
    If forename.Text = data(2) Then
 'first if statement is here \/
        If surname.Text = data(3) Then
            fullname.Text = (data(2) & " " & data(3))
            dob.Text = data(4)
            phone.Text = data(5)
            address.Text = data(6)
            password.Text = data(1)
            found = True
            Exit For
        End If
    End If
Next i
If found = False Then
   Label2.Text = "Sorry, no result found for this student."
   Label5.Text = "Please note this system is caps sensitive."
End If
Dim s As String = ""
forename.Text = s
surname.Text = s
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Check has been declared as string when it should be an integer.
Set option strict to on and infer to off